# What is main difference between the page created through browser and designer, why and how each can be editied?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can't the page created through browser be edited in SP designer [advanced mode] and vice versa?

Comment: what's your SharePoint version, what your site template? what's your page type that created from SPD or browser? please add more details to can help you faster

Comment: Sp2013 and sp 2013 designer